# Create 2D vector from 2 1D vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I am fairly new to vectors and I'm trying to populate a 2D vector from 2 1D vectors for coordinate points. I have 2 vectors like this where source_x and source_y contains values from a file:

```
std::vector<float,T<float>> pos_x(5); 
std::vector<float,T<float>> pos_y(5); 

for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
  pos_x[i] = i+1; //{1,2,3,4,5}
}
for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++){
   pos_y[i] = i+1 ; //{1,2,3,4,5}
}
```

I created my 2D vector like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float, T<float>>> position; 
for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < num ; i++){
         //Output expected: {{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5}}
         position[i][j] = //I'm confuse here 
    }
}
```

I am not certain how to populate pos_x to position[i] and pos_y to position[j].

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want a 2D vector when the inner vector will always have size 2? How about a `vector<Point>`, where `Point` is a struct that has x and y co-ordinates?

Comment: what does T<float> mean here?

Comment: Could I keep the same syntax for my 2 vectors pos_x and pos_y with vector<Point> ? I want to keep it this way for several purpose in my program

Comment: I think you're confused because what you are asking for doesn't make a lot of sense. Howabout showing what you want with a little example? It's not obvious how you can turn 2 1D vectors into a 2D vector.

Comment: T<float> refers to a certain object created in the program

Comment: The obvious issue is that you have `2*num` values in your 2 1D vectors, but `num*num` values in your 2D vector. It doesn't really add up.

Comment: I am just trying to get a vector[x][y] with a vector[x] and a vector[y]

Comment: Ok, why don't you show an example with concrete values?

Comment: Like combining 2 arrays but I was trying to do it with vectors instead. Is that even possible ?

Comment: @Miléna If it is possible with arrays it is also possible with vectors, but nobody here can understand what you want to do with arrays or vectors, please give a small example of what you mean.

Comment: @Miléna Suppose num == 1, pos_x[0] == 1 and pos_y[0] == 2, what values are you expecting in position?

Comment: I changed my code with some dummy values and the expected vector created

Comment: @Miléna I've updated my answer to reflect the example you gave. It's slightly unfortunate that you chose the same values for pos_x and pos_y but I think I've understood now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my guess is this

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> position(num, std::vector<float>(2)); 
for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++){
     position[i][0] = pos_x[i];
     position[i][1] = pos_y[i];
}
```

But I could easily be wrong.

**UPDATE** based on the example in the question I now think this is the correct code

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> position(2, std::vector<float>(num)); 
for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++){
     position[0][i] = pos_x[i];
     position[1][i] = pos_y[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do have another question about 2D vectors. How can I add several elements to a single position ? Example: position[0][1] = [1,2,3,4,5], position[0][2]= [6,6,6,6,6]

Comment: If you want to have a 2D vector, whose elements are themselves vectors then that is a 3D vector like this `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float>>>`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a 2D vector. The truth is that you can create a vector that contains vectors. The first vector is used as an index in the collected vectors.

Note that this concept is similar to a 2D array: `arr[3][4]` means 3 indices, each one points to 4 data.

To create such 2D vector:

```
std::vector< std::vector <float>> positions.
```

Notice I didn't use the second parameter (as in `std::vector<float, SomeAllocator>` because we don't need this custom memory allocator.

Also notice that, contrary to arrays, I did't tell anything about the sizes of each vector, because the std::vector will take care of it.

Let's populate it.

The "main" vector contains vectors. So these secondary vectors may be created before stored in the "main" one.

```
std::vector<float> v1; //secondary
positions.push_back(v1); //add it to main vector
```

Put some values in the secondary:

```
v1.push_back(7.5);
v1.push_back(-3.1);
```

Another way is to access through the main vector. If we new this main vector contains `v1` in its first index:

```
positions[0].push_back(8.); // same as v1.push_back(8.) if positions[0] refers to v1
```

or better using "at": `positions.at(0).push_back(8.);`

Change some value:

```
v1.at(1) = 66.88;
```

or

```
positions[0].at(1) = 66.88;
```

You can also do `v1[1] = 66.88` but prefer the `at()` methof because it will check that index "1" is allowed by the size of the vector v1.

You can create and add another secondary vector:

```
std::vector<float> v2; //secondary
positions.push_back(v2); //add it to main vector
```

and work with it the same as with previous `v1`. Now, `positions[1]` refers to `v2`

I leave the rest of pulling from other vectors to you.